# How do I remove duplicates from an array of structs in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I want to reduce this, note here I have a field which I know to mark as a unique identifier:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: @Beginner Im using CF11. I have tried answering the question myself too :)

Comment: Using the ounce of prevention approach, from there does this array come?

Answer (score 4):

I did it by writing this function (basically copying the keys into a struct if it doesn't exist and adding it to the final array):

```
<cffunction name="RemoveDuplicatesFromObjectArray">
    <cfargument name="objs" type="array">
    <cfargument name="key" type="string">
    <cfscript>
        var keys ={};
        var result = [];
        for (var obj in arguments.objs)
        {
            if (not StructKeyExists(keys, obj[arguments.key]))
            {
                ArrayAppend(result, obj);
                keys[obj[arguments.key]] = true;
            }
        }
    </cfscript>

    <cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
```

and calling it like this:

```
<cfset arr = [{
                    "EXPENSEREPORTID": 129591,
                    "EXPENSELINEITEMID": 602684,
                    "DOLLARSBEFORE": 8.1000000000,
                    "DOLLARSAFTER": 5.4000000000
                }, {
                    "EXPENSEREPORTID": 129591,
                    "EXPENSELINEITEMID": 602684,
                    "DOLLARSBEFORE": 8.1000000000,
                    "DOLLARSAFTER": 5.4000000000
                }]> 
<Cfdump var="#RemoveDuplicatesFromObjectArray(arr,'EXPENSEREPORTID')#">
```

Comment: Thank you, you just saved me a ton of time!

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun since you are on CF11+, I thought I would do it with [ArrayFilter()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayfilter.html) since you might interested in seeing an alternative, but your answer is great (I see Leigh fixed the couple of issues). You build up a struct to match on keys and amend a return array at the same time.

Using a struct as an index will far outperform other methods that might use [ArrayFind()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayfind.html) over larger arrays. What's *even better* is to actually build up a struct over an array from the beginning. In this manner, you don't have to worry about uniqueness. If order is important, LinkedHashMaps are available.

Here is the example:
http://trycf.com/gist/df2fad58219163b7b64c9523b8383921/acf11

```
<cfscript>

data = [
    { 
        dollarsafter : 5.4
        , dollarsbefore : 8.1
        , expenselineitemid : 602684
        , expensereportid : 129591
    }
    ,{ 
        dollarsafter : 5.4
        , dollarsbefore : 8.1
        , expenselineitemid : 602684
        , expensereportid : 129593
    }
    ,{ 
        dollarsafter : 5.4
        , dollarsbefore : 8.1
        , expenselineitemid : 602684
        , expensereportid : 129591
    }
];

function doFilter( data ){
    var index = {};
    return data.filter( function( item ){
      return ! itemFoundInIndexByKey( item, index, item['expensereportid'] );
    });
}

function itemFoundInIndexByKey( item, index, key ){
    var foundIt = index.keyExists( key );
    if( ! foundIt ){
        index[ key ] = '';
    }
    return foundIt;
}

writeDump( doFilter( data ) );
</cfscript>
```

Bonus example concise code (Not using reusable logic for the filter):
http://trycf.com/gist/e3ae76877bdc0809f02ee3333d51f8ae/acf11?theme=monokai

```
<cfscript>

data = [
    { 
        dollarsafter : 5.4
        , dollarsbefore : 8.1
        , expenselineitemid : 602684
        , expensereportid : 129591
    }
    ,{ 
        dollarsafter : 5.4
        , dollarsbefore : 8.1
        , expenselineitemid : 602684
        , expensereportid : 129593
    }
    ,{ 
        dollarsafter : 5.4
        , dollarsbefore : 8.1
        , expenselineitemid : 602684
        , expensereportid : 129591
    }
];

function filterDuplicateObjectArrayByKey( required array data, required string key, index = {} ){
    return data.filter( function( item ){
        if( ! index.keyExists( item[ key ] ) ){
            index[ item[ key ] ] = '';
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}

writeDump( filterDuplicateObjectArrayByKey( data, 'expensereportid' ) );
</cfscript>
```

Comment: That's very cool, i didnt know the new .reduce() function.. Thank you!

Comment: @SajjanSarkar I switched over to Array.filter() instead of reduce since this is more of a filter. It also helps to make it more concise. Of note, you don't have to use a separate function, but this is to demonstrate it.